# Multilple template end tag

Tags: c++, ogre3d

```
Ogre::any_cast<std::map<Rail>::iterator>
```

It takes `Ogre::any_cast<std::map<Rail>` and says too few arguments etc. How can I fix it (other than obvious typedef aliasing)?

Comment: What is with the idiocity around here these days? You can not see I forgot std::map iterator also included the key and instead propose to close the question as too localized and downvote? Please learn to program before starting to stamp votes around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `std::map` takes at least two template arguments - the key type and the value type. Currently you have `std::map<Rail>`. What are you mapping from `Rail` to? For example, this would be okay if your iterators are for a `std::map` that maps from `Rail` to `int` (assuming `Rail` is not a deduced type):

```
Ogre::any_cast<std::map<Rail,int>::iterator>(some_any_object)
```